# Invalid Column name - but it isn't

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, razor

I am getting an "Invalid column" error when I try to view a webpage that displays product data in a WebGrid.

I am currently running a live version of the exact same code, which works. However, this local version isn't working for this 1 particular page.

[image]

As you can see, the code referenced in the picture below *exactly matches* the Column name depicted beneath the error message.

I'm completely stumped. I have no clue what to do right now. It's telling me "invalid column", but it isn't. It's there, and I triple-checked for any spelling errors in my code (which is below), and everything is fine!

What gives?

```
<div id="grid">
  @grid.GetHtml(
    headerStyle : "HeaderStyle",
    columns: grid.Columns(
      grid.Column(
        columnName : "PartNumber",
        header : "Part Number",
        style : "PartNumberStyle"
      ),
      grid.Column(
        columnName : "Product",
        header : "Description"
      ),
      grid.Column(
        columnName : "Quantity",
        header : "Quantity"
      ),
      grid.Column(
        columnName : "ZincPlatedCL2UnitPrice",
        header : "Zinc Plated CL2 Unit Price",
        format: @<a href="?Action=Add&PartNumber=@item["PartNumber"]&Product=@item["Product"]&Type=Zinc Plated CL2 Unit Price&Units=1&UnitPrice=@item["ZincPlatedCL2UnitPrice"]&IsBoxed=0">@item["ZincPlatedCL2UnitPrice"]</a>
      ),
      grid.Column(
        columnName : "ZincPlatedCL2BoxPrice",
        header : "Zinc Plated CL2 Box Price",
        format: @<a href="?Action=Add&PartNumber=@item["PartNumber"]&Product=@item["Product"]&Type=Zinc Plated CL2 Box Price&Units=1&BoxPrice=@item["ZincPlatedCL2BoxPrice"]&IsBoxed=1">@item["ZincPlatedCL2BoxPrice"]</a>
      )
    )
  )
</div>
```

Stack trace

> [InvalidOperationException: Invalid column name
>   "ZincPlatedCL2UnitPrice".]
>   WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord.VerifyColumn(String name) +17193
>   WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord.get_Item(String name) +17
>   WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord.TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder,
>   Object& result) +7    CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>   +140    System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite site, T0 arg0) +432
>   Microsoft.Internal.Web.Utils.DynamicHelper.GetMemberValue(Object obj,
>   String memberName) +26
>   Microsoft.Internal.Web.Utils.DynamicHelper.TryGetMemberValue(Object
>   obj, String memberName, Object& result) +24
>   System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow.TryGetMember(String memberName, Object&
>   result) +57    System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow.get_Item(String name) +58
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String ) +100
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2(CallSite site, T0
>   arg0, T1 arg1) +685
>   ASP.<>c__DisplayClass1f.b__1c(TextWriter
>   __razor_template_writer) in c:\Users\Jase\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\One Stop
>   Fasteners\Shared\Products\TekScrews\SelfDrillingMetalUseCL2.cshtml:98 
>   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
>   System.Web.Helpers.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__f(TextWriter tw) +42
>   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.ToString() +82
>   System.Web.Helpers.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(TextWriter
>   __razor_helper_writer) +1444    System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.ToString() +82
>   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.ToHtmlString() +9
>   System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Object value) +38
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(Object value) +68
>   ASP._Page_Shared_Products_TekScrews_SelfDrillingMetalUseCL2_cshtml.Execute()
>   in c:\Users\Jase\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\One Stop
>   Fasteners\Shared\Products\TekScrews\SelfDrillingMetalUseCL2.cshtml:82 
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1
>   executors) +69    System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>   +151    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +114
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17626 Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Invalid column name
>   "ZincPlatedCL2UnitPrice".]
>   WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord.VerifyColumn(String name) +17193
>   WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord.get_Item(String name) +17
>   WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord.TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder,
>   Object& result) +7    CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>   +140    System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite site, T0 arg0) +432
>   Microsoft.Internal.Web.Utils.DynamicHelper.GetMemberValue(Object obj,
>   String memberName) +26
>   Microsoft.Internal.Web.Utils.DynamicHelper.TryGetMemberValue(Object
>   obj, String memberName, Object& result) +24
>   System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow.TryGetMember(String memberName, Object&
>   result) +57    System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow.get_Item(String name) +58
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String ) +100
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2(CallSite site, T0
>   arg0, T1 arg1) +685
>   ASP.<>c__DisplayClass1f.b__1c(TextWriter
>   __razor_template_writer) in c:\Users\Jase\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\NameRemoved\Shared\Products\TekScrews\SelfDrillingMetalUseCL2.cshtml:98
>   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
>   System.Web.Helpers.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__f(TextWriter tw) +42
>   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.ToString() +82
>   System.Web.Helpers.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(TextWriter
>   __razor_helper_writer) +1444    System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.ToString() +82
>   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.ToHtmlString() +9
>   System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Object value) +38
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(Object value) +68
>   ASP._Page_Shared_Products_TekScrews_SelfDrillingMetalUseCL2_cshtml.Execute()
>   in c:\Users\Jase\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\WebSites\NameRemoved\Shared\Products\TekScrews\SelfDrillingMetalUseCL2.cshtml:82
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1
>   executors) +69    System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>   +151    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17    System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +114
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17626

## Updated: 27/07/2012

---

When debugging, the exception points to this line of code:

```
format: @<a href="?Action=Add&PartNumber=@item["PartNumber"]&Product=@item["Product"]&Type=Zinc Plated CL2 Unit Price&Units=1&UnitPrice=@item["ZincPlatedCL2UnitPrice"]&IsBoxed=0">@item["ZincPlatedCL2UnitPrice"]</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is (without modifications to files) now affecting a total of 22 out of 106 pages. It was only affecting 1 page lastnight. This is strange.

Answer (score 2):

Have you definitely checked your local database to make sure that column is in the schema? Perhaps your local database is "old" compared with your Entity Framework schema.

Comment: Ah, this database was re-created, and isn't based off the existing one. So even though this code's still the same, this is a brand new project/with a brand new db. And I'm doing this all locally too, so I don't see how the old one would play a part in this.

Comment: @EvilCokeMachine: Well, I would double-check that you're *definitely* talking to the database you think you are - and please give more details about the error, including the full stack trace assuming it's an exception. We need to work out whether the error is coming from EF itself, or the database.

Comment: I've checked that I'm def talking to the correct database. I've gone over all of it a dozen times. Are there any tools that you can recommend that will help assist in debugging problems like this a little more?

Comment: @EvilCokeMachine: Well it looks like it's in WebMatrix.Data, which you hadn't mentioned before. I can't say I've got any WebMatrix experience... perhaps there's something there you need to set up?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry about that. I wrote "razor" in the tags which I thought suggested it had something to do with WebMatrix. But I'm not actually using the WebMatrix application, I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC. But if it is a WebMatrix problem, wouldn't it also affect the other 40-odd pages that are of the same type? I'll look into it more though.

Comment: @EvilCokeMachine: Razor implies API.NET MVC to me rather than WebMatrix in particular. If you've got any kind of schema definition in WebMatrix which may not have this field (or may have a typo in it) I wouldn't be at all surprised to see it only affect this page.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that and see if I can find anything. I'm currently updating my question to provide more detail.

Comment: I think I may be getting closer to solving this. I thought that maybe there might be a space infront of, or after the column name in question, but since VS database view won't allow me to "edit" the textbox for that column, there's no way to see how many spaces there are (if any). So I performed a select query in VS (Right click column name > Pane > Ctrl+R, and it displays "`[ ZincPlatedCL2UnitPrice ]`" - you can see that there is a space before and after the column name. And in the same window, the other column names, like "`[GalvanisedUnitPrice]`" don't have any spaces.

Comment: Aside from the space, you've got "Zinz" there instead of "Zinc". Is that just a typo in the comment?

Comment: ...So I went ahead and added those 2 spaces to my code where it references those column names, but I still receive the error " `ZincPlatedCL2UnitPrice`  does not exist." - but I still think these spaces are what's causing this problem.

Comment: Sorry, yeah that's just a typo, I am fixing that now.

Comment: So I can continue working on the site, I'm going to try re-building the database, fixing any spacing-related issues along the way. I just can't think of anything else I can do. I'll keep the question updated with any relevant details as I progress. Maybe if I rebuild the db, I can see where I went wrong.